# How to convert a code into delegate with Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

The Code A works well, I hope to convert it as a delegate.

But Code B fails, how can I fix it?

**Code A**

```
   private val _sortBy=my_sortBy()

    fun my_sortBy():MutableLiveData<ESortBy>{
        val index: String by PreferenceTool( mApplication, "sorByList", ESortBy.DateDesc.toString())
        return MutableLiveData<ESortBy>(ESortBy.valueOf(index))
    }
```

**Code B**

```
   private val _sortBy: MutableLiveData<ESortBy> by {
        val index: String by PreferenceTool( mApplication, "sorByList", ESortBy.DateDesc.toString())
        return MutableLiveData<ESortBy>(ESortBy.valueOf(index))
    }
```

Comment: Would you read https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What delegate do you need and why? If you want to initialize LivaData without `my_sortBy` function, then just use the scope functions.

```
private val _sortBy = MutableLiveData<ESortBy>().apply {
    val index: String by PreferenceTool(mApplication, "sorByList", ESortBy.DateDesc.toString())
    value = ESortBy.valueOf(index)
}
```

or

```
private val _sortBy = MutableLiveData<ESortBy>(run {
    val index: String by PreferenceTool(mApplication, "sorByList", ESortBy.DateDesc.toString())
    ESortBy.valueOf(index)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an assignment (`=`).

```
private val _sortBy = MutableLiveData<ESortBy> by {
    val index: String by PreferenceTool( mApplication, "sorByList", ESortBy.DateDesc.toString())
    return MutableLiveData<ESortBy>(ESortBy.valueOf(index))
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but your code can not be compiled.

Comment: What does it say? I was not able to try it out as I am missing most of the classes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an implementation of your property delegate. For example, you can implement `ReadOnlyProperty`:

```
private val _sortBy: MutableLiveData<ESortBy> by ReadOnlyProperty<Any, MutableLiveData<ESortBy>> { thisRef, property ->
    val index: String by PreferenceTool( mApplication, "sorByList", ESortBy.DateDesc.toString())
    MutableLiveData<ESortBy>(ESortBy.valueOf(index))
}
```

Comment: Thanks! `return` is not allowed in your code.

Comment: @HelloCW you're right, I've updated the answer

Comment: Thanks! your code can work, which way is better between your and Nikola Despotoski ?

Comment: And more,  is `ReadOnlyProperty` keyword? can I rename `ReadOnlyProperty` to other?

Comment: @HelloCW `ReadOnlyProperty` is an interface from the standard library. You cannot rename it, but you can create a type alias and use it instead: `typealias Delegate<T, V> = ReadOnlyProperty<T, V>`

Answer (score 0):

This is matter of which one first gets initialized. Then you need to create and emit the value of in a `LiveData`. You can achieve it by using `LiveData` extension function. Keyword `by` is not available inside function scope, you need to be careful when not to use it.

```kotlin
private val index: String by PreferenceTool( mApplication,"sorByList",ESortBy.DateDesc.toString())
private val _sortBy  by liveData {
        emit(ESortBy.valueOf(index)) 
} as MutableLiveData<ESortBy>
```

You will need [LiveData-ktx](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx#livedata) for using `liveData { }`  delegate